# ActionScripts 3 transfer data to C# MVC

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, data-transfer

I need to pass the byteArray from ActionScripts to the server(MVC on Azure server). 
Prompt how to do it please. It is desirable to be able to track the progress of the transfer. 
Thank you.

Update:

Tried to make a request through the post. Here's the code:

```
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest (path + "/Upload/Upload");
        var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, handleResponse );
        request.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        request.data = result64;
        loader.load( request );
```

If you add events.ProgressEvent, then progres not monitored. The event is not raised.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should add what you have already tried to the post.  And then people will help you with your problems.

Comment: well, what have you tried? you should read the FAQ to understand how this website works. People will happily help you solve problems in your code, but nobody really wants to simply do all the work for you.

Comment: No need to do the job for me. I just want to learn the ways. Keywords say so

Comment: I tried to pass through the post request. But then can not be traced transfer progress

Comment: @Lavios, show us your code. You probably didn't attach a progress listener, did you?